# Change normals after a reflexion on Z axis

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, transformation

I have imported a animated scene from another application. (the meshes, quaternions, and positions). But the Z axis are flipped. I have to make a scale(1,1,-1). The problem is my normals are now wrong thus making the lighting inverted too.

What's the best strategy to solve this problem ?

(I thought chaging the up in my camera but then I need to invert the Z position of all the other objects)

Best regards and thank you for your help,

Guillaume Leclerc

Comment: this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485105/1980846, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16840273/1980846 and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4904

Comment: the side parameter does not work because I apply the reflexion on the Mesh matrix and not the Geometry.