# ThreeJS BufferGeometry flipping

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, buffer-geometry

I want to flip mesh object across specific axis(X, Y or XY) and I have applied matrix same as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625199/threejs-geometry-flipping) to the mesh object and indeed it is working when I'm using an `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry` instance.

But I'm rendering thousands of object so performance is major concern therefor I have to use `THREE.BufferGeometry` to gain good performance but my changes in matrix to get flip object cause the problem. After that objects are not visible anymore. 

Is there something that I have to care for `THREE.BufferGeometry` in this case?

Comment: Dou you render the meshes from both sides? `side: THREE.DoubleSide`

Comment: @marcel Its worked. Thanks a lot. You saved me :) Does it make any difference in performance?

Comment: yes `side: THREE.DoubleSide` has a hit on performance. a better approach is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21485105/1980846